# Stretching a curve towards one general direction without changing two points in a curve

Tags: functions

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to "stretch" the following curve $f(x) =  \ln(x + 1)$ so that it appears similar to the green curve I have drawn in the above picture. The blue arrow indicates which general direction I need it to stretch.

I need to stretch this curve while maintaining two coordinates: $(0,0)$ and $(50,\ln(51))$ such that the original curve and the new curve both contain these coordinates. Is there any way to do this?

-Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let $\ell(x) = \frac{\ln(51)}{50}x$. This is a straight line between your two fixed points. Note that $f(x) - \ell(x)$ is zero at the two fixed points, and positive everywhere in between them. So, if we add some multiple $k$ of $f(x) - \ell(x)$ onto $f$, then we will get a "higher" curve that still passes through the two points. In other words, the desired green curve, $g$ is given by

$$g(x) = f(x) + k\{f(x) - \ell(x)\}$$

Choose $k$ to get the best fit. In your case, it looks like $k=1/2$ would be about right. This would give us

$$g(x) = \frac{3}{2}\ln(x+1) - \frac{\ln(51)}{100}x$$

Answer (score 1):

A hint: Choose units so that the point $(50,\log 51)$ becomes $(1,1)$. Let $x\mapsto f(x)$ $\ (0\leq x\leq 1)$ be the resulting function for the given blue-grey curve. Then consider the family of functions
$$\phi_n(x):=\root n \of {f(x)}\qquad(n\geq1)$$
and choose $n$ to your needs.